# Filter groups on whether the max of one column, subject to a condition on another, is equal to a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to slice (or filter for) those groups (Though, I'd settle for rows.) that belong to groups in `d2.groupby('g')` where the max of the values of `s` in the group, for rows where `test` is `1`,  is 2.

```
pd.__version__
# '0.24.1'

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'g': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'test': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   's': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

d2
   g  test  s
0  1     1  1
1  1     1  2
2  1     0  3
3  2     1  1
4  2     0  2
5  2     0  3
```

In plain English: **I want to keep groups where the maximum value of `s` that has a corresponding `test` value of 1 is 2.** For the example below, I want to keep the `g` group `1` because the second row has `test == 1` and `s == 2`, and the third row has `s == 0`. Expected output for this data:

```
   g  test  s
0  1     1  1
1  1     1  2
2  1     0  3
```

I've tried `d2.groupby('g').filter(lambda x: (x.test == 1)) # followed by nonsense`, as well as `d2.groupby('g')[[d2.s == 1]] # with more nonsense`. The latter gives me the message about Series objects being mutable and unhashable. I've tried a number of other equally senseless and useless approaches. *How do I `groupby('g')` and filter by the max of `s` where `test` is `1`?* This seems like it should be easy, but I can't get it. I *could* get there by adding a column, but that seems like a kludge.

Note: I have searched for the answer for this. I'd gladly take any search hints about how to find any current solutions for this question, if there are any. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` to compute a mask, something like this:

```
df[df['s'].where(df['test'] == 1).groupby(df['g']).transform('max') == 2]

   g  test  s
0  1     1  1
1  1     1  2
2  1     0  3
```

The idea behind `Series.where` is to let us only consider values of "s" where "test" is 1.

Here's a similar version above inspired by WeNYoBen which will work because "test" is 0 or 1 here.

```
df[df['s'].mul(df['test']).groupby(df['g']).transform('max').eq(2)]

   g  test  s
0  1     1  1
1  1     1  2
2  1     0  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter`

```
d2.groupby('g').filter(lambda x : (x['s']*x['test']).max()==2)
Out[390]: 
   g  s  test
0  1  1     1
1  1  2     1
2  1  3     0
```

---

Another way using `isin`  ***since `filter` usually slower in big data frame***

```
s=d2.s.mul(d2.test).groupby(d2['g']).max()==2
d2.loc[d2.g.isin(s.index[s])]
Out[394]: 
   g  s  test
0  1  1     1
1  1  2     1
2  1  3     0
```

Comment: Don't forget the disclaimer that `filter` is on the slower side of things :)

Comment: I like the idea behind multiplying "s" and "test"! Very clever.

Comment: My actual data has a more complicated structure in its equivalent to the `test` column, so the generic check is more useful to me. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate it's cleverness, too. I just tried to construct a clear example, and wouldn't be able to directly use the rather specialized multiplication technique IRL.